# convert a column of integer to minutes

Tags: integer

In my dataframe, I have a column called "duration" with integers. I would like to convert all the integers in the column to minutes. This was what I wrote:

df_new['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df_new['duration'], unit='min')

output: 'duration': dtype('<m8[ns]') which is incorrect
it should be 'duration': dtype('float64')

Can anyone help please?